# How to change ActorSystem in play.core.server.NettyServer

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using NettyServer to start a play web application. I am wondering if there is a way to use an existing Actor instance, and pass it to the NettyServer. Here is my code:

```
val server = NettyServer.fromRouter(ServerConfig(
  port = Some(1000),
  mode = play.api.Mode.Dev)) {
  case GET(p"/index") => Action {
    Results.Ok(s"OK")
  }
}
```